# How can a record data class be autowired in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-record

I have Spring project with the following record.  I need it autowired in my classes, but I can't run the Spring Boot app anymore.

The reason:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in sk.eea.jira.rest.Issue required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration.
```

Record class:

```java
@Component
public record Issue(String assignee,
                    String created,
                    String reporter,
                    String resolution,
                    String status,
                    String summary,
                    String updated,
                    String key) {
}
```

How can I autowire such records in Spring?

Comment: Autowiring is for _services_, not request-specific data. A `record` should never be annotated `@Component`, semantically.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- this is not true, there are `@Component` with request scope defined in spring which could also be autowired. That is why Spring offers different component scopes

Answer (score 4):

Your case has nothing to do with records.

How will spring inject those values in parameters of constructor? Dependency injection can not be done in your case.

You can define a bean in your configurations manualy

```
@Configuration
public class CustomConfigurations{

   @Bean
   public Issue getIssue(){
    return new Issue("","","","","","","","",);
   }
}
```

This will make autowiring work.

But in the end it does not make any sense to autowire a `Issue`

This is a Pojo object created only for some specific request.

Comment: Whan I need is accessing this POJO whenever I autowire after receiving List<Issue> as json on controller. I have data on controller but would like to without storing to database accessing from Service class. Is something like this even possible?

Comment: You must pass this information from controller to service as method argument